# Virtualbox vagrant guest can not use host DNS

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

On my company Windows 10 host I can successfully `ping a.b.c`.

I have vagrant guest on Virtualbox and when I call `ping a.b.c` I got error `Unknown host`

I found that I should use `natdnshostresolver1 on`. But it didn't help me. I use network with NAT mode and I would like to keep it unchanged.

When I call `ping google.com` I got correct answer, so I have problem only with company DNS

Comment: is `a.b.c` an intranet domain and picked up by your win10 via your corporate DNS? if so you may try use your Windows DNS with vagrant

Comment: @hkdtam Good idea. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that however on guest `ping a.b.c` does not work but `ping a` works fine.

That is enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/BerlinVagrant/vagrant-dns) may be a good starting point?

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.